# is it possible to multiply the value of an input box this way?

Tags: jquery, math

I have an input box, but I want an easy solution to multiply it by 2. What is the correct way to achieve this below:

```
var input2 = parseInt($('#bx2').val() * 2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't changing the value of the element. The easiest way to do this would be to pass a function to the `.val()` method, parse the value and then simply multiply that by 2.

```
$('#bx2').val(function () {
  return parseInt(this.value, 10) * 2;
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan I'm a fan of [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), since you never know for sure.

Comment: Nice job for also including the correction of parseInt(value, 10) to ensure base-10 parsing

Comment: Yeah, we needed the radix too :)